# Chapter Title Does Not Align With Text Width

Tags: align, chapters, titles

I am trying to modify my chapter titles so that in the case of a long title, it remains aligned with the text width. I have tried commands like `\newline`, but this conflicts with the use of `hyperref`. I have included a MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge}{\chaptername~\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*-3}{*6}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
 
\chapter{This Chapter Title Is Nottt Aligned}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The problem is evident from the below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Probably, latex doesn't know where to hyphen the word *Nottt*, and you should make a line break by hand.

Comment: @Bernard By line break do you mean `\newline`?

Comment: Yes something like that. Of course, I suppose you don't want the line break in the header, so you should also use the optional argument of `\chapter`.

Comment: @Bernard Will this cause the chapter title to appear over two lines in the TOC? This is not desirable.

Comment: I suppose that if it fits in the header, it will also fit in a single line of the toc.

Comment: @Bernard If you would like to put this into an answer, i'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's necessary, as I'm pretty sure there are already answers  on this topic (don't know where exactly, unfortunately).

Comment: @Bernard I used `\newline`, but the chapter title now appears over two lines in the TOC...

Comment: Did   you use the optional argument without line break?

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean  to use `\chapter|title without line break]{title with an explicit line break}`.

Answer (score 4):

At `\Huge` size, with “Chapter 1.” at the beginning it’s quite hard for TeX to find suitable break points.

I suggest to typeset the titles ragged right.

Below are also two examples: the second title is justified with `\linebreak` to suggest a good break point; the third title uses `\\` and you see that the final output is just the same as the first one, which doesn't need special marks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  showframe, % to show the page boundaries
]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be last

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\bfseries\Huge\filright}% ragged right
  {\chaptername~\thechapter.}
  {0.5em}
  {}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*-3}{*6}

\begin{document}
 
\chapter{This Chapter Title Is Nottt Aligned}

\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax % so we can set the three titles on the same page
% let's use justification by way of example
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\bfseries\Huge}% justified
  {\chaptername~\thechapter.}
  {0.5em}
  {}

\chapter[This Chapter Title Is Nottt Aligned]
  {This Chapter Title Is \linebreak Nottt Aligned}

\chapter[This Chapter Title Is Nottt Aligned]
  {This Chapter Title Is \\ Nottt Aligned}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The part between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is just to show the examples.

[image]

There would be different ways to solve the problem. Probably `\Huge` is too big.

This is with `\bfseries\LARGE\filright`

[image]

And this is with `\Large\scshape\filright`

[image]

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to make the chapter heading ragged right rather than justified in this case since **Chapter *x*** takes up a lot of space and there isn't much space left for the rest of the heading. And hyphens in headings don't look so good.

e.g.,

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\Huge\raggedright}{\chaptername~\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Simple and elegant.